# How does this code behave with more than 32GiB RAM?

Tags: memory

The point here is to test **how many bits are reserved in a 64-bit kernel for the reference count**. For example, `ByteCount[5]` reports 16 bytes for a machine integer; there is no reason to distrust this count. Since 8 of these bytes are obviously used for the integer `5`, and at least 4 bits are needed for the `Integer` tag, that leaves at most 60 bits remaining for the reference count. How many bits are actually used for the reference count? It could be 60, 32, 31, ..., Lets find out. **Unfortunately, large amounts of RAM are need to find out** (More than I have). The code below tests for reference counts of 31 bits. It should be clear how to test for different numbers of bits.

Start by measuring the memory currently in use and add a fairly large array `s` of pointers to strings. This is needed so that we essentially eliminate the noise after allocating and freeing the next huge array. The part that tests the reference count is in `x`, which is a huge array of pointers to the array pointed to by `s`. Each of these pointers increments the reference count of the object `{"Hello, world!",...}`. Obviously, if this reference count overflows, this object will be lost by the kernel, and clearing `x` and then `s` will not recover this block of a million pointers. The difference `m3-m1` will then be about the same as the difference `m1-m0`, indicating the the memory is indeed <s>permanently lost to the kernel</s> leaked by the kernel.

Please note that in constructing `x`, the kernel will be completely *unabortable* as it fills in the huge array of pointers. Also, note that the `blah` after the definitions of `s` and `x` are needed, otherwise the r.h.s. of the definitions are stored in the `Out` variable, which would completely destroy the measurements.

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    slen = 1000000;
    xlen = 2^31 + 10;
    m0 = MemoryInUse[];
    s = ConstantArray["Hello, world!",slen]; blah;
    m1 = MemoryInUse[];
    x = ConstantArray[s,xlen]; blah;
    m2 = MemoryInUse[];
    Clear[x];
    Clear[s];
    m3 = MemoryInUse[];
    Round[({m1,m2,m3}-m0)/($SystemWordLength/8)]
```

**EDIT:**

I am getting frustrated by the obtuseness of the high-ranking officials here. The title of the question is clear. The code is clearly written in code format. There is even a clear explaination of why I want the code to be run. I will reiterate the demands of the question.

1. I do not have 32GB ram.
2. I do not know anyone who has 32GB ram.
3. The code I wish to run requires at least 32GB ram for smooth running.
4. The code is not dangerous, just unabortable from within the kernel.
5. The code I wish to run is in the code block.
6. If you have 32GB ram or more, could you run the code and report the result?

Epilogue: The nice user dwa is well on the way to accomplishing this task below. I simply want a follow-up with `xlen=2^30+10`. I would upvote this answer, but I simply do not have the reputation to do so. The answer from ilian does not include such numbers and is a restatement of the original question.

**Edit:**
There is no need of a follow-up from dwa. The leak indicated in dwa's answer is a real leak and it is *by design*, as clarified in the comments below.

Comment: Do you experience a specific problem? Or is this just the result of your observations?

Comment: I have updated the post will bold around the main points. I am asking for help from someone with 32GB of ram or more.

Comment: @ilian, Let us not get into motives quite yet. Do you have a system that can run this code comfortably?   PS I find it odd that a WRI rep can casually admit to the effect of "yeah, our reference counts overflow past 31 bits". Do you not realize what a huge admission this is?

Comment: There are plenty of limits one can run into on any software system. For example, iterators and array indices can only be machine integers. It is easy to run into trouble with very deep arrays too, and one could wait for a while for a simple input like `Permutations[Range[20]]` to return. So I am not getting the point of either the question or of your comment remarks.

Comment: Yes ilian, it is perfectly clear that neither my post nor my first comment has been understood by you, and your comment about permutations misses the mark again. Did you downvote this question because you don't want others to see what you wrote in your first comment (which I see has been deleted now)? Or, did you downvote because you don't understand it? If the point of the question is not clear, I have clearly indicated many times that it can be resolved by running with sufficient RAM. I am waiting for such a nice person.

Comment: Asking people to run their machines into a possibly uninterruptible state, and arguing with a very experienced person on MSE, one who has stress-tested the software professionally, just makes no sense. Especially given that the question is likely to be unanswerable even if someone runs the requested test, and the premise that up to 60 bits are available is off base (the justification made no sense).

Comment: Daniel L., would you mind explaining better what is wrong? I clearly indicated how much memory will be needed, and that this is higher than I or most other people are running. The paragraph with a fair warning about an unabortable calculation applies to the _kernel_ and not to the machine itself. One may kill a _process_ anytime. Also, the justification for having at most 60 bits is completely correct. Such mistakes in arithmetic are likely the reason that the current memory manager is, as one might say, dirty at best.

Comment: A runaway kernel quite often cannot be killed. This is unfortunate but not something I can solve; I frequently need to reboot in such circumstances. As for the reference counter, it is an signed int of some type, probably 32 bit. Signed ints generally do not have 60 bits. The claim that this counter must have bits it cannot use is garbage (there is no reason to expect the type tag is in the same structure field or anything like that).

Comment: If the kernel is stuck in a loop filling in a array that is not being swapped, any os should allow you to kill this process right away. That is why I have repeatedly emphasized 32GB. I never claimed that the counter definitely has space for 60 bits. I claimed that the counter has space for at most 60 bits. There is a clear difference in these claims, and I hope that the reasoning in the question is clear on this point. Also, it would be nonsense to have a 60 bit counter in a 32 signed int, but keep in mind that not all counters have to be c types.

Comment: If one makes the further assumption that the count fits neatly into a c type, then 32 signed bits would the next logical choice, and you will see that this is exactly what I proposed testing. However, I didn't allow myself such a luxery when making the general argument. Please let me know if this makes sense. It seems like everything I have written has been misunderstood.

Comment: Also, it again seems odd that a dev is arguing that 60 bits is a nonsensically high precision for a reference count in a 64 bit kernel. If I were arguing for the integrity of a memory manager, this is not quite the argument I would be making.

Comment: There is a claim that "and at least 4 bits are needed for the Integer tag, that leaves at most 60 bits remaining for the reference count. This is false (the ref count is an integer type and uses all its bits). There is a claim that "Obviously, if this reference count overflows, this object will be lost by the kernel". This also is false (a refcount overflow makes an expression "sticky" and it will not get freed, quite the opposite of being lost to the kernel). The issues of when an OS will get into swap territory are complex. Suffice it to say that RAM is much but not all of the story.

Comment: ...Moreover, I made no claim to the effect that 60 (or 64) bits is nonsensically high. A signed 64 bit int could in fact be used. It could bloat the memory footprint somewhat if the actual size is currently 32 bits (I have not checked this of late). The tradeoff in the memory manager is not between refcount integer size vs losing expressions but between that size vs marking exprs as sticky so that they never get freed. I mention this because it is not clear (to me at least) what is meant by "integrity of a memory manager".

Comment: (1/3)I would move this to a chat, but reputation is lacking. First, the point on 60 bits such an elementary one that I hope we can get past it. Here it is spelled out: I do not have the kernel source code in front of me. I can only argue about the size of members based on the information content of these members, and that the fact that the total size does not exceed 64 bits (8 bytes). These 64 bits need to contain at least 4 bits of information to distinguish the at least 10 types of expressions. This leaves at most 60 bits of information remaining for the reference count. It is that simple.

Comment: (2/3)Now, I suspected that the kernel devs (and your presuppositions confirm this) would not have the imagination to pack information in any more of a creative way than by using the c types of 32-bit, 16-bit, and 8-bit ints. This would then clearly leave a 32-bit int as the logical choice for the count. However, such a conclusion is not strictly warranted from my point of view. Please let me know if I am being clear on this point. Your repeated ungenerous interpretation of my first paragraph leaves me sceptical that this point is getting through.

Comment: (3/3)Finally to the point about leaking: I am using the phrase "lost to the kernel" in the cs 101 sense of a memory leak. You have now said it yourself that the kernel is never going to free the array initially pointed to by `s` since it got upgraded to "sticky". This also means that this memory cannot be re-purposed for later use. If this is not a leak, I do not know what a leak is. This also seemingly directly contradicts the second paragraph of the documentation
http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MemoryManagement.html

Comment: Your (1/3) is kinda loopy (except the part about lacking rep, which is entirely understandable). the "spelled out" issue is, still, ignoring everything you have been told about the ref counting. Okay, fine. Your (2/3) is mostly, well, heat rather than light. As for (3/3), I think I was clear that a ref count overflow would lead to a memory leak. What was lacking to that point was any indication that "lost to the kernel" might mean "memory leak" (it's really not clear wording if that was the intent). This is far from the worst cause of such leaks. Over and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get {1000403, 2148484430, 1001237} as the final output.

Comment: dwa, I thank you profusely for your timely and excellent response. Your numbers look plausible I will accept you answer once I get feedback on the following points:

Comment: Nevermind. Your one run is enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is somewhere between a comment and an answer (to the real question, not the "run my code for me" part).

The premise of the question seems to be this: the reference counting mechanism used by the kernel for memory management of expressions has limitations.

Apparently the big discovery is that a finite number of bits is used to store the count, so at some point there inevitably will be wraparound and very bad things will happen, like the computer catching fire or ... a memory leak.

To OP's credit, the included code example illustrates this well. There was indeed one whole megabyte of memory leaked, for a computation that requires many gigabytes to begin with.

Can this be addressed in the kernel? Sure, for example it could use at least as many bits as the pointer size is and then the refcount will never wrap around.

Should it be addressed? In the absence of any implications of practical significance, maybe not yet. It is not worth bloating the size of *every single expression* for what is a questionable benefit.

But if the OP feels strongly about this issue and it is impacting their work, they are more than welcome to submit a bug report to WRI Technical support.

Comment: Now we have hit the nail on the head. However, I regard the "run my code for me" as the real question and dwa's answer as the real answer. This answer is restating the question. I will accept dwa's answer as soon as the cross over point is found by dwa.

Comment: Why on earth would you edit and thus resurrect this embalmed corpse? Did you never see Karloff in [The Mummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mummy_(1932_film))? I seriously need to get a good amulet.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau it's all part of ilian's plan to subtly drive you mad by making you think that "run my code for me" questions might deserve thoughtful answers. Less The Mummy than [Gaslight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslight_(1944_film)).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, Bergman and Boyer. Great flick (I never knew about the older one though). Still on the market for an amulet, just in case. And maybe something [to ward off vampires](http://unvarnished-truth-olbuzzard.blogspot.com/2017/10/halloween-viewing.html).